# How to find the sequence number of a key value pair in a list

Tags: python, boto

The following code is working as expected. I know the reservation ID **50b4f837** and I could find the instance related to that reservation.

```
>>> reservations = conn.get_all_instances()
>>> reservations
[Reservation:r-cded15ae, Reservation:r-50b4f837]

>>> instances = reservations[1].instances
>>> instances
[Instance:i-5ffecc27]
```

The problem is that I need to find the instance programmtically without returning all the reservations and then manually calling the specific key (1 in this case).

I will supply the reservation ID and it should return the instance ID.

Comment: What data structure is `reservations`?

Comment: It would be easier to answer, if you explained what `get_all_instances` does, what `__repr__` of `Reservation` and `Instance` returned, how the classes are defined, etc, pp, ...

Comment: Use a dict structure instead of a list...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the reservation ID and if all of your reservations are for a single instance, you could do this:

```
import boto.ec2

ec2 = boto.ec2.connect_to_region('us-west-2')
instance = get_all_instances(filters={'reservation-id': 'r-50b4f837'})[0].instances[0]
```

Again, this would only work if your reservations always contain a single instance (i.e. you only call `run_instances` asking for a single instance.